# Android: Rotate to face

Tags: android

Does anyone know of an animation/method that can rotate an image around smoothly to face a point, such as where the user is touching?

Answer (score 1):

This one does a full 360 flip, but you can adjust the code to your needs, so that it stops at an angle where the users tipped the screen:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Comment: I meant 2D rotation, a-la Asteroids-style?